# Set Fallback Font globally in Flutter

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, I do set the fallback font on every single text widget like that:

```
Text('Sample, style:'TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontFamilyFallback: ['AppleColorEmoji']))
```

I can set the text font in `ThemeData` as `fontFamily` , but not the fallback font.

Is there any alternative?

Comment: `DefaultTextStyle`?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to define a general theme for a Flutter app is through the `theme` attribute of `MaterialApp`. You can do it like this:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  title: 'Sample App',
  theme: ThemeData(
    // Define the default brightness and colors.
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    primaryColor: Colors.lightBlue[800],
    accentColor: Colors.cyan[600],

    // Define the default font family.
    fontFamily: 'Georgia',

    // Define the default TextTheme. Use this to specify the default
    // text styling for headlines, titles, bodies of text, and more.
    textTheme: const TextTheme(
      bodyText2: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontFamilyFallback: ['AppleColorEmoji']), // Default style for Material Text
      subtitle1: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontFamilyFallback: ['AppleColorEmoji']), // Define your own style of subtitle
    ),
  ),
  home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Sample title', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1)), // Use your default config like this
      body: Text('Sample content'), // Without style, it will use your bodyText2 config
  ),
);
```

Read more on Flutter's `Theme` [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes)

**Updated:** To only set a fallback Font globally for your app, use the `DefaultTextStyle` at the root widget. For example:

```
Scaffold(
      body: DefaultTextStyle(
        style: TextStyle(fontFamilyFallback: ['AppleColorEmoji']),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const Text(
                'The first text',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

You can read more on the `Text` [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html) here

> The style argument is optional. When omitted, the text will use the style from the closest enclosing DefaultTextStyle.

Comment: Sure, but this then only applies to bodyText2 and subtitle1 (or any specified). Any way like the `fontFamily`?

Comment: @NicolasDegen I've updated my answer. Please check

Comment: Cool. Better would be to wrap the entire app with it:) Does this override all text styles from ThemeData?

Comment: Yes, since the Text widget will catch the closest enclosing DefaultTextStyle, it will overwrite the ThemeData. Btw I'd appreciate a lot if you mark the chosen answer ^^

Comment: I have to first try out if it does only override the fallback font;)

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work when wrapping the app widget..

Comment: Yeah it has to wrapped inside the MaterialApp widget, since if wrapped outside, the DefaultTextStyle of the MaterialApp widget will take over since it's the closest