# Flutter - Text Widget does not render currency icons

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-text

In my application, I have a screen that shows pricing. However, the currency icon does not appear correctly in some places (look at the amount 7000). This problem is more frequent on iOS devices, with a few occurrences on Android devices.

The information is retrieved in the following manner:

```
Text("₹ 7000.00") // in application the pricing is retrieved from api call.
```

The currency icon is included in the data I receive from the api request. "₹7000" is an example.

The font used is `Gotham Rounded`. Is this due to the font's inability to render currency icons? What is the best way to resolve this problem?

[image]

Comment: This is because of the font, use `fontFamilyFallback`. try this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68693134

Comment: @nitishk72 does `fontFamilyFallback`  render alternate fonts if the current one not render properly

Comment: Do i need to add another fonts on pubspec?  and add that to fontFamilyFallback ?

Answer (score 3):

It's better to use Unicode characters for currency symbols because most of the symbols are not yet supported in flutter so your device does not understand the string so it does not render it on mobile.

Unicode characters on the other hand could be easily translated after compilation

You can find unicode characters for different symbols [here](https://unicode-table.com/en/)

So you have something like this instead

```
Text("\u{20B9}");
```

Comment: For „₹“ is U+20B9 the currency symbol

Comment: Yeah I just editted it thanks

Comment: @Denzel Correct me if I'm wrong, If the symbols aren't yet supported shouldn't the symbol on the button not be rendered?

Comment: You're not wrong but usually to avoid the anomaly we use unicode characters